# C language : variable not initialized

Tags: c

Hello I was coding three individual programs that each tell you how many days there are in a specific month of the year, calculates how much money you have left after riding a bus, and a calculator program.

In my opinion, the first two programs do not affect the last program, and calculator programs works fine individually. However, once I add the /* */, and block out the first two block of codes, the last calculator program does not function saying that the variable answer is not initialized. The code is pasted below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

// program telling you days in a month

    int month;
    printf("Choose month > ");
    scanf("%d", &month);
    puts("");

    switch (month) {
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 5:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 10:
    case 12:
        printf("%d th month has up to 31 days\n", month);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Feburary has 28 or 29 days\n");
        break;
    case 4:
    case 6:
    case 9:
    case 11:
        printf("%d th month has up to 30 days\n", month);
        break;
    }
    puts("");

// Balance calculating program

    int balance = 10000;
    char choice;

    printf("Choose between Adult (g) or Student (s) g /s > ");

    while (getchar() != '\n');

    scanf("%c", &choice);
    puts("");

    switch (choice) {
    case 'g':
    case 'G':
        balance -= 1250;
        puts("Adult fee is 1250 won\n");
        break;
    case 's':
    case 'S':
        balance -= 720;
        puts("Student fee is 720 won\n");
        break;
    }
    printf("balance : %d", balance);
    puts("");

// Calculator program

    char cal;
    double num1, num2, answer;

    printf("Calculator \n");
    printf("Choose the type of calculation + , - , * , / > ");
    scanf("%c", &cal);
    puts("");

    while (getchar() != '\n');

    printf("input two numbers > ");
    scanf("%lf%lf", &num1, &num2);
    puts("");

    switch (cal) {
    case '+':
        answer = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case '-':
        answer = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case '*':
        answer = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case '/':
        answer = num1 / num2;
        break;
    }

    printf("%.2f %c %.2f = %.2f", num1, cal, num2, answer);

}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Show the code that doesn't work and not the code that does. Also, give the **exact and full** error. The last `switch` statement does not have a `default` case and the `answer` was not initialised. Which means it's possible for `answer` to have no set value when the `printf` is run. That's probably the error you are getting.

Comment: aside: you'll want to flush stdout after  prints not ending in newlines since the stream is initially line-buffered

Comment: The issue is really "why doesn't the compiler complain that `answer` might be used uninitialized when the three independent program fragments are combined in a single function?"  And that isn't clear, but it gives a good reason to create and call separate functions for separate tasks.

Comment: What is `answer` if `cal` is not one of `'+'`, `'-'`, `'*'` or `'/'`? Simply initialize `double num1, num2, answer = 0.;` will resolve the issue. (always initialize your variables as you are learning C)

Comment: There could be a fault arising from `scanf("%c", &cal);` which in each use of `%c` should be like `scanf(" %c", &cal);` with an added space.

Comment: @kaylum: Re “Show the code that doesn't work and not the code that does”: No, both are relevant since there is an issue of why the warning is not given for the “working” code.

Comment: @Rafael: Flushing should not be needed in good C implementations when input is solicited. C 2018 7.21.3 3 says “… Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment…” with a caveat that support for these is implementation-defined.

Comment: All of your `switch` statements should include a `default` case.  which does something reasonable, even if it only prints an error and exits.

Comment: Where does one program begin and where it ends?  please, read [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as it is impossible to know how do you use the programs and how the data is passed from one to the next.

Comment: @EricPostpischil sure, since input is requested on the same stream, its write buffer *should* be flushed prior to reading, but since that's implementation defined, i wouldn't interpret that as, "flushing should not be needed..." so, i wouldn't overlook "When a stream is line buffered, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block *when a new-line character is encountered.*"